# How can I map values in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


Y = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1, 3, 4, 0, 1]))

print(Y)

Y[Y[0]] = np.array(0, 0, 0, 0)
Y[Y[1]] = np.array(1, 0, 0, 0)
Y[Y[2]] = np.array(1, 1, 0, 0)
Y[Y[3]] = np.array(1, 1, 1, 0)
Y[Y[4]] = np.array(1, 1, 1, 1)

print(Y)
```

This is what I'm doing. I'm trying to get as an output:

```
[[1 0 0 0], [1 1 1 0], [1 1 1 1], [0 0 0 0], [1 0 0 0]]
```

However, instead, I get an error:

```
    Y[Y[0]] = np.array(0, 0, 0, 0)
ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are giving `np.array` a list of arguments, namely zeros and ones. Try packing them with brackets like the one you feed to `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: @HåkonT. can you give me an example please?

Comment: Sure, I mean that `np.array(0, 0, 0, 0)` should be `np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They way I interpret your question is to fill ALL the DataFrame rows that match for example `0` with [0, 0, 0, 0], which in your case is just one row, but for `1`, there are actually two rows that should be replaced.

I have changed to using letters instead of numbers to make it easier to see:

```
# Initialize DataFrame with zeros:
Y = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,4), dtype=int), index=list('bdeab'))
```

Now:

```
print(Y)
```

gives:

```
   0  1  2  3
b  0  0  0  0
d  0  0  0  0
e  0  0  0  0
a  0  0  0  0
b  0  0  0  0
```

If we now do:

```
mapping = {
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'b': [1, 0, 0, 0],
    'c': [1, 1, 0, 0],
    'd': [1, 1, 1, 0],
    'e': [1, 1, 1, 1]
}

for row in pd.unique(Y.index):
    Y.loc[row, :] = mapping[row]
```

We get the desired DataFrame:

```
   0  1  2  3
b  1  0  0  0
d  1  1  1  0
e  1  1  1  1
a  0  0  0  0
b  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
yourary=pd.DataFrame([np.ones(x) for x in Y[0]]).fillna(0).values
yourary

Out[63]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```